# The true definition of invariant functions on Matrix algebra

Tags: matrices, continuity, matrix-calculus, invariant-theory

According to terminologies in "Invariant theory" a true  definition for an invariant  function $f:M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\to  \mathbb{R}$ is  the  following:

**Definition 1:** A  continuous  function $f$ is invariant if $f(A)=f(P^{-1}AP)$  for every  $P\in Gl_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

But  I found the  following  alternative definition in some  papers:

**Definition 2:** A  continuous  function   $f$ is  invariant if $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for all $A,B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$

> Are these two properties  equivalent for  a  continuous $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are.

## $1\implies 2$:

If $B$ is invertible, then it is a member of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$, therefore according to definition $1$,
$$f(BA) = f(B^{-1}BAB) = f(AB)$$

If $B$ is not invertible, then you can find a sequence $B_n$ of invertible matrices that converges to $B$ (for example, $B-\alpha_n I$ where $\alpha_n$ converges to zero and avoids the eigenvalues of $B$), and then due to continuity and the result above,
$$f(BA) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(B_nA) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(AB_n) = f(AB)$$

## $2\implies 1$:

Here we don't even need continuity:
$$f(P^{-1}AP) = f(APP^{-1}) = f(A)$$

Comment: Thank you very  much for your  answer.